# $scope.$parent's Object getting lost when accessing data from childScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

```
.controller('mainApp.qaModule.controller.questionVoteMeta', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log("Test", Object.keys($scope.$parent), $scope.$parent, $scope.$parent.questionValues);
}])
```

**output** is

[image: Image shows the output.]

for some reason the **questionValues** Object is lost.

Comment: $scope.$parent.questionValues is _undefined_

Comment: can u shoe the child scope and parent scope structure